# Failed to load API caused by strange ambiguity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've fixed a bug causing a "Failed to load API" error on local IIS startup (swagger UI).

My function in the controller class was

```
public async Task<Data> myFunction()
```

And `Data` is a public class defined under the same name in 2 separate files : `File1` and `File2`
(different properties, only same name)
Therefore it was ambiguous.

However even after explicitly passing `Data` as `File1.Data` in the controller function

```
public async Task<File1.Data> myFunction()
```

It still fails to load the API, until i change the class name completely.
Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: C# has no concept of files. What namespace is each type defined within?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Under the same namespace. I suppose that is why it is behaving this way?

Comment: Yes, type names must be unique within a namespace. If you want to create multiple `Data` classes, then each would need to be in a different namespace.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay much to learn, thank you

Comment: As a sidenote, I wouldn't normally call a class Data. It's much too broad. Name your two data classes after what data they contain.